# Dynamically create buttons that toggle visibility of links

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of links:

```
<ul>

<li class='season1'>season1 episode1</li>
<li class='season1'>season1 episode2</li>
<li class='season1'>season1 episode3</li>
<li class='season1'>season1 episode4</li>
<li class='season1'>season1 episode5</li>

<li class='season2'>season2 episode1</li>
<li class='season2'>season2 episode2</li>
<li class='season2'>season2 episode3</li>
<li class='season2'>season2 episode4</li>
<li class='season2'>season2 episode5</li>

<li class='season3'>season3 episode1</li>
<li class='season3'>season3 episode2</li>
<li class='season3'>season3 episode3</li>
<li class='season3'>season3 episode4</li>
<li class='season3'>season3 episode5</li>

</ul>
```

Can I use jQuery to generate buttons that will toggle a class to show only a specific season?

Comment: Can you confirm or correct: you want to automatically set the class based on the content? If so I can answer you.

Comment: I whant to automaticle create the links / buttons, the classes i already have.

Comment: OK, I'm writing an answer now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just hide all links and show only those of a specific season.
e.g.

```
$("[class^='season']").hide();
$(".season2").show();
```

You'll have to bind this to some button or link.

Creating the links & binding:

```
$("ul li").each(function (i, e) {
    if ($("button." + e.className).length) return; // Already exists

    var $button = $("<button>").addClass(e.className).html(e.className);
    $button.click(function () {
        $("li").hide();
        $("li." + this.className).show();
    });
    $("body").append($button);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o656mbnL/

Comment: is it possible to create the button or links by jquery?

Comment: thanks. works great, is it possible to have a button says ALL, and show some how wich one is active.

Comment: For the all button you can just bind `$("li").show()`. To show which one is active just set the text of some element.

Answer (score 0):

Let's put some buttons in your HTML:

```
<button id="season1">Season 1</button>
<button id="season2">Season 2</button>
<button id="season3">Season 3</button>
<!-- Existing code here -->
```

Now, with jQuery, you can trigger a function with each button click:

```
function show(season) {
    $("ul > li").hide();
    $("ul > ." + season).show();
}

$("#season1").click(function () {
    show("season1");
});

$("#season2").click(function () {
    show("season2");
});

$("#season3").click(function () {
    show("season3");
});
```